# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when i want to edit?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner, i have a problem  when i click a link-button named "Edit" on gridview , it throws an error saying **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"** .

can you please also refer me to some sites to get a proper understanding in case i get the same error next time or any tip that will help i must be aware of.

See my code below;

```
protected void grdDepartment_command(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow _Row = gridDepartment.SelectedRow;
    // it shows the error here.
    string str = _Row.Cells[0].Text; 
    ViewState["DepartmentID"] = str;

    IList<MCX.ISupplierPortal.Database.dptDEPARTMENT> _EditDepartment = _decDepartment.GetDepartment(int.Parse(str));

    if (_EditDepartment != null)
    {
        foreach (MCX.ISupplierPortal.Database.dptDEPARTMENT _DepartmentList in _EditDepartment)
        {
            txtDepartmentName.Text = _DepartmentList.DepartmentName;
            txtDescription.Text = _DepartmentList.DepartmentDesc;
            ViewState["DepartmentID"] = _DepartmentList.DepartmentID.ToString();
        }          
    }
    ViewState["PageMode"] = "Update";
}
```

The exception occurs here

```
GridViewRow _Row = gridDepartment.SelectedRow;
// it shows the error here.  
string str = _Row.Cells[0].Text;
ViewState["DepartmentID"] = str;
```

Comment: At which line you are getting exception? Have you tried debugging it using debugger?

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/05/06/why-do-i-get-the-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object.aspx), then come back to the problem

Comment: did you check `if(_Row.Cells[0]!=null)` ?? However, this is common issue which can be easily find by debugging!

Comment: `GridViewRow _Row = gridDepartment.SelectedRow;` is incorrect. Give this a try instead `GridViewRow _Row = Ctype(e.CommandSource,GridViewRow);`

Comment: check if `gridDepartment.SelectedRow` is not null

Comment: Also, isn't _Row null? Why do you expect that gridDepartment.SelectedRow has the value you want? You should pass the row id (or something like that) in CommandArgument of the button, and then get `gridDepartment.Rows[index]`. Pressing a button does not select a row for you.

Comment: @KayNelson question is tagged C# not VB.NET, and regardless, [SelectedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx) is already a `GridViewRow` so no cast is needed.

Comment: have you thought, what will be the selected row before selecting??

Comment: @James, correct that was a bit sloppy of me.

Comment: @MR E could you please post us the code from the markup, that is related with the GridView? Thanks !

Comment: @MR E one thing, I just noticed and it seems to me strange is the name of the handler you use. That's the reason why I asked you before to post use the code that's related with the GridView in the markup. Specifically, I can't understand why you don't use the event SelectedIndexChanged? Please look here if you have any question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(_Row!=null)
{
    string str = _Row.Cells[0].Text; -->it shows the error her.
    ViewState["DepartmentID"] = str;

    IList<MCX.ISupplierPortal.Database.dptDEPARTMENT> _EditDepartment =_decDepartment.GetDepartment(int.Parse(str));

    if (_EditDepartment != null)
    {
        foreach (MCX.ISupplierPortal.Database.dptDEPARTMENT _DepartmentList in _EditDepartment)
        {
            txtDepartmentName.Text = _DepartmentList.DepartmentName;
            txtDescription.Text = _DepartmentList.DepartmentDesc;
            ViewState["DepartmentID"] = _DepartmentList.DepartmentID.ToString();

        }                   
    }
    ViewState["PageMode"] = "Update";
}
```

You should check if the selected row is not null. If it is not, then you can execute the code you have written. Otherwise, the selected row is null. Hence the selected row doesn't point to an object in the managed heap. So you cannot try to read the properties of an object that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
GridViewRow row = gridDepartment.Rows[ Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
if(row != null)
{
       //do work
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried and it works too..am glad that i have learn two things at the same time